# Turkey transit visa for a stateless person?

Tags: visas, transit, turkey, bulgaria, stateless-persons

I am a stateless person but I am a resident of Uzbekistan. I am going to visit Bulgaria on the 16th of August this year. Unfortunately there is no direct flight to Bulgaria so I have to fly through Istanbul. In this connection do I need a Turkey transit visa if I only stay in Turkish International Airports for not more than 3 hours waiting for my next connecting flight? If so, how long will consider my deal? And how can I speed up the process of getting transit visa? Can I get the visa in the airport? How much will it cost?

Comment: May I ask because I am confused. does being stateless mean you have no passport? if no passport how come you travel?

Comment: @MeNoTalk: a person is stateless is not a citizen of any country. This can happen because the country the person comes from has revoked their citizenship or has ceased to exist. Stateless persons travel on other travel documents, such as [1954 Convention travel document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_Convention_travel_document) or a certificate of identity issued by the country where they reside.

Answer (score 3):

When in transit at Ataturk international airport, you do not pass through passport controls. Therefore, you would not need a transit visa.
However, if you have to pick up your bags and re-check your bags, or if you have to move from Ataturk to Sahiba Gokcen (or vice versa), you *will* go through passport control and *will* need a transit visa.

I don't see how being stateless affects any of this, but I might be missing something.