# Can I travel to France with my wife who does not have a visa?

Tags: visas, france, stateless-persons

Can I travel to France with my wife and child? I have a British passport and so does our daughter, however my wife has a **UK stateless travel document**. We are looking to travel this Christmas to her parents' house, because they have not seen the child yet.

Can we travel without a visa for my wife with her UK stateless travel document?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what the French consulate general [has to say](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/Visa-for-family-of-an-European):

> The foreign spouse of a EU national enter France without visa if holding:
>
> - A valid travel document ;
> - A valid UK residence permit with the endorsement **"family member of EEA national"** (this endorsement is compulsory to be visa exempted);
> - **and** if they are joining or travelling with the EU national.
>
> **Attention:** To avoid unnecessary problems whilst travelling it is advisable to carry along evidence of family relationship.

It seems to be immaterial that the travel document is not a passport, as long as it is valid.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8738/46 which includes "if granted, a stateless persons' document is normally valid for travel to all countries"

Comment: Thank you so much, so we should not have any problems travelling.

Comment: @Greg14 In particular she needs to bring _both_ her travel document _and_ UK residence permit.

Comment: From an unfortunate similar but different experience as an EU citizen with non-eu spouse, i can tell you that it is not only about the rules of the country you are traveling to. Even if you have the appropriate documents, the airline employe at service might not have the same interpretation and won't let your wife board the airplane. Therefore please also check with the airline. Transavia once refused my wife boarding a plane flying within Schengen under similar conditions. Eventually, we won the court case, but it was a headage.