# I don't know my nationality. How can I visit Denmark?

Tags: visas, passports, thailand, denmark, stateless-persons

I was born in a Thailand refugee camp to Vietnamese parents, but quickly as an infant, they immigrated to Denmark. We lived there for 10-11 years and then moved to the U.S. I am a green card holder of U.S. and I plan to travel to Denmark but I cannot get a U.S. passport (not a U.S. citizen) and I can't get a Danish passport either since my nationality has not been established. Who can help me answer those questions?

My mother and I have a joint Danish travel document (I don't have a passport because I was not issued one since I was young) and my mother claims she doesn't either. However, how did we travel to Spain, Romania, and France from Denmark (via airtravel) and not have one??  Our travel document doesn't indicate where we've traveled. I reallly really really need help because I have called the Danish Consulate/Embassy as well as Thai Consulate and no one is able to give me any answers.

I cannot get a visa to Denmark because when they ask what country I am a citizen of, I can't answer that.

Comment: Exactly what "joint Danish travel document" do you have? How did you get a US green card? The answers to these are very important because they will indicate what options may be open to you.

Comment: I think this link will be useful: https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/D4en.pdf You can get a USA refugee travel document without citizenship. You are eligible as a Green Card Holder who was formerly a refugee (if, of course, that is how the USA classifies you; you don't make that clear). I expect you are too old for the joint document with your mother,

Comment: Thank everyone for participating. I am not a refugee of the U.S. so I dont think it applies to what Andrew Lazarus mentioned.

Comment: I am a U.S. green card holder & I'm just trying to travel for a month to Denmark & Spain but I cannot find out which country i am a citizen/national of before I can apply to the visa of that country. Also a "joint Danish travel document" was a document for my mother & I's visa to travel to U.S. before we got sponsored and resided here. @Michael Hampton

Comment: Once you are *inside* the Schengen area, which includes Denmark, Spain and France (and quite likely Romania, though I'm not certain), the requirements for border crossings are significantly reduced. It's possible that at that point nobody felt any need to verify your citizenship.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by " I am not a refugee of the U.S."  There is not such a thing as a refugee "of the US." Did you mean " I am not a refugee in the U.S." which is not true?

Comment: See if this answers help: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/how-to-travel-if-you-are-stateless and also this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refugee_travel_document

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: We're somewhat hampered by not knowing when this was -- e.g, before or after Denmark implemented Schengen. (Which by the way, Romania hasn't yet). Quinn, when are you born? When did your relocation to the U.S. happen?

Comment: @QuoraFeans There is such a thing as a refugee of the U.S. (literally, someone who is fleeing from the U.S. government,) but they're not likely to help you leave the country in that case. :)

Comment: @reirab: and  besides  Snowden, who is a refugee of the US?

Comment: @QuoraFeans Everyone for whom an arrest warrant has been issued who is attempting to evade arrest, I suppose, just as with nearly any other country. At any rate, my comment was tounge-in-cheek.

Comment: http://storbritannien.um.dk/en/travel-and-residence/danish-passports-and-travel-documents/danish-travel-documents/

Comment: it's strange/amazing that you have a "green card" given the situation described.

Comment: You're either a Vietnamese citizen *vis a vis* your parents or Vietnamese & Thai depending on if Thailand considers birth inside its borders qualification for automatic citizenship. Did you receive a birth certificate upon birth? That will be a big clue as to where you should seek a passport from.

Answer (score 163):

From your description it appears that you are stateless -- that is, no country recognizes you as its citizen. That makes international travel difficult, but what's generally supposed to happen is that the country where you're legally resident (that is, the United States) can issue you a passport-like document which can serve as an *identification document* while traveling but does not declare you to be a citizen of anywhere.

In most of the world this would be known as a "1954 convention travel document", but the US is not party to the 1954 Convention. Instead the USCIS can issue something called a [U.S. Re-entry Permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Re-entry_Permit), which a number of countries, including Denmark, recognize as equivalent to a 1954 convention document.

[**Beware**: As of 2017-04-09, the [official lists of travel documents accepted by Schengen member states](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas_en) indicate that Denmark *does not* recognize US "permits to re-enter" but *does* recognize US "refugee travel documents". They are the same kind of booklet, but have different heading above the photo. There are different boxes you need to check on form I-131 when applying.]

After getting a re-entry permit you will still need to apply for a Danish visa, since you're not a U.S. citizen (who are visa-free in the Schengen area). On the visa application form, you would put "stateless" as your nationality and check "other travel document" rather than "ordinary passport". You would need to support your visa application with extra good evidence of ties with the US that motivate you to leave the Schengen area after your proposed trip (a green card is a good start here, but by no means sufficient), and having spent your childhood here is not going to make it easier. But it's not categorically *impossible*.

In the long run it would probably be in your interest to pursue naturalization as a U.S. citizen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38679/discussion-on-answer-by-henning-makholm-i-dont-know-my-nationality-how-can-i-v).

Answer (score 83):

Henning Makholm's answer addresses the issue of your possible statelessness, and suggests a way of obtaining a travel document.

The other alternative is to acquire a citizenship. Your case is complicated and I would recommend consulting an immigration lawyer. Below is some relevant information, mostly extracted from Wikipedia. Note that it is possible that you are not in fact stateless (e.g. if you are considered a citizen of Thailand or Vietnam), but merely lack documents to prove your citizenship.

### Thailand

[Thailand's nationality law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_nationality_law) is based on the principles of both [Jus sanguinis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_sanguinis) (citizenship through parents) and [Jus soli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_soli) (citizenship through birth). Your parents were not Thai citizens, so that leaves birth. [This paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_nationality_law#Jus_soli) provides a summary.

### Vietnam

Wikipedia doesn't have an entry for Vietnam's nationality law, but searching Google produced hits for me that [suggest that the principle of Jus sanguinis (citizenship by parents) applies](http://vietnam.embassy.gov.au/hnoi/Vietnamese_nationali.html), so you may be considered a Vietnam citizen regardless of the fact that you were not born there.

### Denmark

There was a real missed opportunity here as you and your family would have been entitled to acquire citizenship after being resident here for [9 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_nationality_law#Naturalisation_as_a_Danish_citizen) (known as [naturalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalization)) but as you have permanently become non-resident since then, that probably doesn't count for anything anymore. On the other hand, you say you have a travel document jointly with your mother. What kind of travel document is it? Presumably you used this document to enter the USA. How did you address the issue of your citizenship at that time?

### USA

You didn't specify how long you have been resident in the USA for, but you should be able to naturalize as a citizen if you have been a [permanent resident for 5 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship_in_the_United_States#Pathways_to_citizenship). If this is the case, this is probably the easiest option as you can easily establish your case.

### Dual / Multiple Citizenship

As it is possible that you may be eligible for two or more of the above citizenships, you may want to carefully consider your options. The laws regarding [multiple citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_citizenship) can be complicated and vary for each country. Many countries, and particularly Asian countries, forbid multiple citizenship. So e.g. by taking up USA citizenship you may cut yourself off from the others. Whether or not this matters to you depends on what your long term plans are and where you intend to eventually settle. One downside of USA citizenship (and almost uniquely in the world) is the requirement to file US tax returns for the rest of your life (while you remain a citizen), even if you stop residing there (you may or may not have to actually pay US taxes, depending on your income and other circumstances).

Comment: +1, most likely the OP is already Vietnamese and just needs his and his parent's birth certificates (possibly a nationality lawyer) to establish his claim. There are thousands of Vietnamese in (or were in) the same situation.  The claim to Thai and Danish citizenship is less tenable, but it's great you mentioned it for completeness.  Great answer reflecting great research.

Comment: There's some evidence that Vietnam revokes or revoked citizenship of overseas Vietnamese citizens - see http://vietnamembassy-usa.org/consular/instructions-registration-retain-vietnamese-citizenship (or http://moj.gov.vn/vbpq/en/lists/vn%20bn%20php%20lut/view_detail.aspx?itemid=10451 in more detail)

Comment: Note: U.S. citizenship doesn't mandate filing U.S. taxes "for the rest of your life", if you consider the option of moving elsewhere **and** renouncing said citizenship. However, I think I recall reading somewhere that the process is not very simple and/or not free of additional monetary cost.

Comment: Just to be clear, the U.S. requirement to file tax returns abroad **doesn't involve paying any actual taxes unless you make quite a lot of money** (you can exclude a large amount of income--currently about $100,000 plus housing expenses).  For most people this is just a paperwork annoyance, not a cost, and U.S. citizenship is likely a net benefit.

Comment: @iszi That is true, but then you wouldn't be a US citizen, so my statement still holds. The cost of renouncing isn't the only issue - you also need to make sure that you have a citizenship elsewhere, to avoid become stateless.

Comment: @dan1111 That is true for many cases, but there are many subtle issues that can crop up that aren't easily covered by the exemption and/or double taxation treaties. Obviously that's too off-topic to go into much detail here, but it's important to at least be aware of it for if/when that situation arises. The simple (and most common case) is someone who works a job and receives a salary, below the threshold. It becomes more complicated once other income sources and asset ownership/disposal come into it.

Comment: @JBentley My point is, U.S. citizenship is not a life sentence to being subject to U.S. tax codes. There *is* an exit path. So if naturalizing in the U.S. is the only/best/fastest route to achieve a certain goal, you *can* do it without being *irrevocably* chained to a life-long obligation. Your statement was that USA citizenship requires you to file US tax returns "for the rest of your life" - as an unqualified statement, that is factually untrue. Accurate phrasing would be "for the lifetime of your U.S. citizenship".

Comment: @iszi I've updated to take account of your comments. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how realistic an opportunity Danish citizenship would have been. Not only must you have been resident for a certain period of time; there's also a language proficiency requirement and a civics test. The fact that the OP's mother chose to relocate to America shortly after she would have had enough residency to petition for naturalization could hint that she had not become sufficiently immersed in Danish society to meet these additional requirements.

Comment: @dan1111, due to [FATCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Account_Tax_Compliance_Act) things are actually more onerous than you might think.  Banks abroad must report to the U.S. government quite a lot of information on any U.S. citizens with accounts, or face crushing fines.  As a result, many overseas banks refuse to allow American clients.  Just last November in Switzerland I spoke with a mixed Swiss-American family where the son, a dual citizen, found it nearly impossible to find a bank to keep his accounts in due to the unreasonable reporting requirements.

Comment: @Kyralessa that is interesting but a different issue from taxes.  Also, Switzerland is an extreme outlier in terms of banking privacy regulations.  As a U.S. citizen in Britain I can easily bank anywhere I want, and I would expect the same to hold true throughout the European Union.

Comment: @JBentley true, but those are edge cases.  I wanted to counter the perception that U.S. citizens abroad have to pay double taxes, which isn't true for most people.

Comment: @dan1111, it's something that affects Americans who live anywhere in the world other than the U.S., not just Switzerland or even Europe.  Many citizens have renounced because of FATCA.  It's a significant problem for U.S. citizens who don't live in the U.S.  You should not lightly dismiss it just because you don't happen to know what it is.

Comment: @Saheb Thanks for the proposed edit, but actually the correct term is [multiple citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_citizenship) (singular), not multiple citizenships (plural). Similar to how you would say dual nationality and not dual nationalities.

Comment: @kyralessa is right. I know a fair number of (non-rich) people born in the US, now in the UK, who've revoked their US citizenship over various requirements of FATCA. Whatever they may be, they are clearly considered onerous by many US ex-pats. I've also seen a fair number of "No Americans" clauses in (admittedly slightly niche) financial services operating in the UK.

Answer (score 18):

> I don't know my nationality. How can I visit Denmark?

Simple! talk to **[USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/)** (could be as simple as using **Ask a Question** link on their website) and ask them that. Since they issued you a green card they will know your exact status in their records. They can best tell if you are a citizen of any country according to their records or not

Depending upon their answer you can then chose the best course of action later

Comment: But USCIS doesn't have anything to do with foreign nationalities. And the US doesn't care about what foreign nationalities a permanent resident has. A permanent resident could have gained or lost nationalities since becoming a permanent resident; USCIS would not know anything about that. The most you can get is a copy of the forms you filled out to apply for things with USCIS, to see what you wrote back then, but that would be information that you would already know. USCIS is not qualified to determine whether the country you claimed to be a national of actually consider you a national.

Comment: "USCIS would not know anything about that." Why would you say that? I would expect the USCIS to be the go-to expert for all things related to entering and leaving the country. They work closely with other agencies and, at the very least, will be able to help you interface with the other countries.

Comment: @user102008 I'm surprised that *U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services* has nothing to do with immigration and we random folks on internet with some up-votes know better? Yes it wouldnt care much about nationalities gained later on but it would definitely know on which status they applied for green card when the OP was a child with his mother. If OP knew they have gained a nationality later they wouldnt be asking this question in the first place

Comment: @corsiKa: "I would expect the USCIS to be the go-to expert for all things related to entering and leaving the country." Actually, USCIS has nothing to do with entering or leaving the country. CBP has to do with entering the country.

Comment: @HankyPanky: I didn't say they didn't have to do with US immigration, but with foreign nationality. The only time when nationality comes up in applying for a green card is that the OP (or parents) filled out a form where the OP put a country on there as their nationality. The burden is on the person filling it out to provide the right answer. USCIS does not, for the most part, care about what is put there, because the current nationality doesn't really matter for US immigration purposes. Getting a copy of a form that you filled out in the first place does not provide you with any information.

Comment: @HankyPanky: That would be like saying that if you don't know what your marital status history was, to just ask IRS, because the IRS has a lot to do with whether you were married or not, because the filing status on the tax form is supposed to be based on your marital status. But of course it's you who filled out the form in the first place. So you would only be getting your own claim, and not anything more.

Comment: @user102008 - You keep saying things like: the OP filled out the form in the first place You seem to not take into account that the OP was only (about) 11 years old when they entered the US. OP has not likely ever seen any of the entry application/forms and much or all of the information they contain might be new information for OP. Even OPs mother, she might have had assistance filling out the forms (due to language) and she might be mistaken about what she might recall about the information that was entered on the forms. It's certainly possible that there is no useful (new) ----->

Comment: @user102008 ... information there, but it's also quite possible that there is. I don't know, entirely all the types of information on the forms, or what information might have been collected 10 or 20 years ago (or whenever, I don't know when OP entered the US). Perhaps there is an indication of OPs refugee status, which they might not know the facts correctly now.

Comment: While it is quite probable that there are claims or information on the old forms that are new to the OP, it is very much worth noting the age of the information and possible (in)validity issues regarding its source. Anyone who has tried to track their genealogy can tell you that facts get screwed up in immigration processes, especially when translators are involved and especially when it might be in the immigrant's best interest to not be wholly truthful about their origins.

Comment: Is it a good idea for the OP to go to the USCIS and get copies of the original forms used to apply for their green card? Most certainly. But any information recovered from those forms should be *very thoroughly* vetted and re-validated before using it for any official purposes (e.g.: applying for visas, passports, citizenship, etc.) elsewhere.

Comment: @KevinFegan: The question is only about nationality. It might make sense to get a copy of what they filled out for the nationality question -- *if* they have no idea now what nationalities they could possibly have, to get a starting point (and even then, they might have had multiple nationalities and only put one, or they put one that wasn't actually correct; so they can't rely on it; it can only serve as a hint) -- *but*, the OP actually already has a very good idea what one or two countries he could have the nationality of, so such a hint provides him no information.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are mainly concerned with stating what your nationality is on the Danish visa application form.

Since you have a US green card and you do not hold a passport, you would likely be traveling with a US re-entry permit (Form I-327), which is a passport-like booklet issued by USCIS that says “Travel Document” on the cover and is used in lieu of a passport. You would be submitting the re-entry permit to apply for your Danish visa, instead of a passport, and the visa sticker would be placed in your re-entry permit.

The re-entry permit [lists a nationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Re-entry_Permit#/media/File:US_Re-entry_Permit_(USCIS_I-327).jpg), which would be the “country of citizenship” that is listed in field 5 of the Form I-131 you use to apply for the re-entry permit. Whatever nationality USCIS prints in your re-entry permit (which, based on other answers, may be Thai, Vietnamese or stateless) is the nationality you should fill out on the Danish visa forms. The Danish authorities are unlikely to question the nationality stated by USCIS or ask for further evidence.

(The nationality you provide on Form I-131 should match what you have previously told USCIS when you applied for the green card, or you might be asked to provide further evidence.)

The short, pragmatic answer to your question is: **use whatever nationality is printed in your re-entry permit,** unless it is clearly wrong.

The “joint Danish travel document” you are referring to is most likely a “[fremmedpas](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/DNK-JO-05002/index.html)” or “alien’s passport”, which is like the US re-entry permit and is issued to Danish residents who are stateless or unable to apply for a passport from their home countries, usually refugees. The Danish alien’s passport will also list a nationality, and ideally that would also match the nationality in your US re-entry permit; if not, you might be asked to explain the discrepancy, which might actually be relatively easy  due to the objective confusion about your nationality.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to address this would be via a birth certificate and the easiest route will likely be Thailand. Thailand extends citizenship to anyone born there.

If you were issued a birth certificate in Thailand, then it's quite likely you can approach the Thai Embassy in the US to confirm and issue citizenship documentation/passport.

If you weren't issued a birth certificate, contact the Thai Embassy anyway. With sufficient documentation surrounding your time there they should be able to confer citizenship.

Comment: Do you have links to official sites which confirm this?

Comment: Merely being birth in Thailand does *not* appear to guarantee you Thai citizenship: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_nationality_law