# Can a stateless person travel to all Schengen areas? (holding Bruneian International Certificate of Identity)

Tags: schengen, stateless-persons, brunei

I have this problem: I am stateless from Brunei. Can I apply for a multiple entry Schengen visa? Does anyone have this experience?

I am planning to visit Schengen countries so I really want to know how to do the process. Am I allowed to travel Schengen visa as a stateless person?

Additional: 
I would like to clarify for my questions. Currently, i am holding Brunei International certificate identity/Alien passport so my status is known as Stateless although i born in Brunei i have to follow my father nationality as stateless.To be honest, my dad also born in Brunei following his family emigrate to Brunei. My country have not recongnise me as citizen.

Previously i ever visit Germany which is i know i require visa and get approval but i am only allow to visit Germany by the time so now i am about to planned visit Spain via Germany because i planned visit Germany and Spain during summer holiday. Is there any alternative way for me to get Schengen visa enter for both countries?

Comment: What kind of travel document do you have and from which country? Which Schengen country(ies) specifically do you want to visit?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this question may help a little: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/how-to-travel-if-you-are-stateless?rq=1

Comment: You may not need a visa at all. It depends on which countries you are intending to visit (there are no Schengen wide rules on this subject) and exactly which travel document you have or are able to be issued.

Comment: Wikipedia says the [Bruneian ICI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruneian_International_Certificate_of_Identity) isn't recognized by Spain. Maybe you could call the Spanish embassy in Malaysia to confirm or ask if any other travel document is possible?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold.